# preprocessing_function in ImageDataGenerator tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image not appllied

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, conv-neural-network, imagedata

I was trying to use ImageDataGenerator and apply a prepocssing function to apply some random hue. When I run transformation on a single picture via ImageDataGenerator, I dont see its applied.

```
def hue_change(image):
new_img = tf.image.random_hue(np.array(image), 0.2)
return new_img

IMG_gen = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=30,height_shift_range=0.05, width_shift_range=0.05,fill_mode='nearest',
                         zoom_range=0.03, rescale=1./255,preprocessing_function=hue_change)
```

When I apply this directly function directly into the picture, it works.

```
plt.imshow(hue_change(imread('Train//Apple Granny Smith//179_100.jpg')))
```

but when I generate it via random_transform

```
plt.imshow(IMG_gen.random_transform(imread(('Train//Apple Granny Smith//179_100.jpg'))))
```

I don't see any changes.

Would you be able to advise why it works like this?

Answer (score 0):

I tried the hue_change preprocessing function using the ImageDataGenerator.flow_from_directory and displayed the results which were correct. The hue changed randomly. I also tried your code on an image

```
dgen=ImageDataGenerator(preprocessing_function=hue_change)
nimage=dgen.random_transform(image)
plt.imshow(nimage)
```

As you note this does NOT modify the hue. The random_transform in itself should apply a random transformation on the image. I do not know why it does not. Perhaps the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47461538/keras-imagedatagenerator-random-transform) may help.

Comment: That not supposed to be a problem, because I would receive in error that array does not match. It seems like, it did not even try to convert it into hsv. I might try to apply this after IMG_gen was applied as form of different approach.